# would it be faster to parse XML from url or to save the informations in a database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, xml

I am relatively new to the development of a website with asp.net (C#) and SQL server 2008 (until now I was using php/mySQL). And I am currently facing some choices and any suggestion to help me make them would be really appreciated:

I have a Database (let's call it DB_A)  wich is running under SQL server Express (2008). And I can't modify it (but I can use it or do a copy (DB_C)  . The problem is that this DB is updated  every day, so is it possible to do an update of the copy periodically as well ?

Furthermore, I have to take some informations by parsing an XML file which is in the web. 
So I was wondering if it was faster to parse it directly with C#, whenever there is a request to the pages that need these informations or would it be better/faster to parse it once periodically (automatically) and save the datas in SQL tables (in DB_C) ?
But I don't know if the last method is even possible.

One scenario would fold like this : the website only connects to DB_A and the others needed informations would be directly gotten by parsing the XML (from an url ).

Does someone has any suggestions about this please ?

Comment: How often does that XML change (if not often, you could cache the file locally)? How often do you need the info in that file? How complex is it to parse that file? (if often and/or complex, you might want to do it once and save the results). In short, reccomendations depend on a lot of external factors that you didn't specify.

Comment: For your second/main question: have you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394005/what-is-faster-reading-an-xml-file-or-querying-a-database?rq=1) SO question? The underlying implementations are different but the main questions seems similar.

Comment: @Hans the XML probably change only once a week (it is about 46 ko), I need the informations for some pages of the site, which would be visited pretty often. The XML structure is fairly simple.

Comment: @Jordy Yes I read it, but my XML file is updated periodically, and I don't know if it is possible to parse it automatically once a day and to save the datas in a database. Like simsim suggested I will see if it is possible to use a batch, but I fear some issues that may prevent the batch from launching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For the first part, Copying the database and sync changes:**

I suggest implementing a ***Replication*** solution, replicate data from main DB to your copy.

Check Microsoft article [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd323622.aspx) for some info of the available replication scenarios that you can select from.

**For the second part, parsing the XML data:**

This depends on the data itself; If the data is very large, needs a lot of processing, business validation..etc, and the data is not needed to be updated immediately, sure you wont have to parse it by each request
Just run a periodic parser to work on the XML that is sent to you, a separate job from your website i.e: a service/a batch/... etc

Otherwise (data is sensitive), I think you need to parse it with each request.

But it all depends on the business requirements of your webapp

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will check about the Replication, as for the XML it is about 22000 characters, and the structure is fairly simple. Well it is not needed to be updated immediatly ( at least once a day) . That is why I don't know if there is really a need to create another database just for these informations.

Comment: Logically speaking, from business perspective: if the info in your XML is not related to the data in DB_C, It wont matter if it was on a separate Database or in the same one.
From Technical perspective: If you go the the replication solution to copy DB_A into DB_C, there will be no conflicts if DB_C have extra tables, so you can create some tables for storing info found in the XML

Comment: I see, but do you think it is possible to create a batch that would lauch itself periodically and parse the XML file and then save the datas in DB_C ?

Comment: I'm sure there is a neat way to do that, but unfortunately, I'm not aware of it now, need some reading to do :)
But I would start looking on how to create a windows scheduled task to run a console application (exe), but there might be better ways to do it